# How Can i add Library Jar files into the modules

Tags: java, spring, module

> I am trying to use loaded jar files of my class path into my module. I
> know requires will accept only modules names.
> my jar files are present inside the Spring Jar Files folder.
> I tried to use @Configuration annotation inside my appConfig.java file and IDE could not recognize it.

Your help is much appreciated as I am new to the programming world.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I use Maven or Gradle to handle all the jars.

It seems you have just started with Spring.
I suggest you try Spring Boot with Maven or Gradle to manage the library and the code lifecycle (compile, build, test).
This is one tutorial for example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.
[Example link](https://www.edureka.co/community/4028/how-to-import-a-jar-file-in-eclipse)

The above solution is obviously a "Quick" one. However, if you are working on a project where you need to commit files to the source control repository, I would recommend adding Jar files to a dedicated library folder within your source control repository and referencing few or all of them as mentioned above.

I'd suggest go for the second one if you are planning to build this as a proper project and put it in a source control repo.